# Detecting black screen in Power Point slide show after the last slide

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I would like to trigger some action in my PowerPoint Addin after the user navigates away from the last slide and when the black screen appears.

According to various [resources](http://officeone.mvps.org/vba/events_version.html) i can handle the display of the last slide in the slide show (by uising SlideShowNextSlide event) as well as the slide show end event (SlideShowEnd), but there is no information on how to detect that the slideshow is displaying that black screen before it ends.

Any ideas or pointers to resources are highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

```
SlideShowWindows(1).View.CurrentShowPosition
```

will tell you what slide you're on. If you're on the black slide at the end of a show, it will return a number one higher than the number of slides in the actual presentation.

Don't forget that a given copy of PPT may be set NOT to show the black slide at end of show (File | Options | Advanced ).  If so, the snippet of code above will error.  You'll want to trap for that.

Comment: thanks for the feedback. Now i have another problem - on which event should i hook this check so i can trigger my logic?

Comment: PPT may or may not trigger the events you mention above when it moves to the black slide; I just tested and found that it doesn't fire the OnSlideShowPageChange event when moving to the black slide.  Have you tested the other two events?

Comment: I have tested all available SlideShow events, as well as some auto-macros. No one of them is triggered during this transition, it's like the SlideShow falls in a limbo state.

Comment: The only other idea that occurs to me (and I've done no testing whatever) would be to trap the slide show end event when the user ends the show, restart the show and force it to navigate to Slides.Count + 1

Comment: Tested with SSW.View.GoToSlide Slides.Count+1 - it throws an Out of range error. Seem like a real black hole for VBA handling. Thanks for the ideas though, they are valuable.

Comment: If you manage to work this out, please do post here; I'd be interested to learn more.  And if I stumble across a solution I'll do the same, of course.

Comment: I need to disable End with black slide pro-grammatically how can I do this

Comment: If you're starting PPT up programmatically, you could first set HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\14.0\PowerPoint\Options SSEndOnBlackSlide to 0.  It'll only work if PPT isn't already running, though.  Otherwise, I think you'd have to use SendKeys.